# How to make Laravel work with Redis cluster on AWS

Tags: php, laravel, redis, laravel-5.4, predis

I'm trying to use Laravel (5.4) with a clustered version of Redis. I followed the instructions form [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41091103/laravel-predis-redis-cluster-moved-no-connection-to-127-0-0-16379/41256321#41256321) like so:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Redis Databases
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Redis is an open source, fast, and advanced key-value store that also
| provides a richer set of commands than a typical key-value systems
| such as APC or Memcached. Laravel makes it easy to dig right in.
|
 */

'redis' => [
     'client' => 'predis',
     'cluster' => 'true',

     'default' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST_1', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => 6379,
            'database' => 0,
     ],


    'clusters' => [
         'default' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST_1', '127.0.01'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => 6379,
            'database' => 0,
        ],
        'jobs' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST_2', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port'     => 6379,
            'database' => 0,
        ],
        'content' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST_3', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port'     => 6379,
            'database' => 0,
        ]
   ],

    'options' => [
        'cluster' => 'redis'
    ],
]
```

but I keep on getting this error

```
[2019-06-07 15:53:37] local.ERROR: Predis\Response\ServerException: MOVED 5873 127.0.0.1:7001 in /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/predis/predis/src/Client.php:370 Stack trace: 
0 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/predis/predis/src/Client.php(335): Predis\Client->onErrorResponse(Object(Predis\Command\StringGet), Object(Predis\Response\Error)) 
1 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/predis/predis/src/Client.php(314): Predis\Client->executeCommand(Object(Predis\Command\StringGet)) 
2 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Redis/Connections/Connection.php(72): Predis\Client->__call('get', Array) 
3 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Redis/Connections/Connection.php(84): Illuminate\Redis\Connections\Connection->command('get', Array) 
4 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/RedisStore.php(54): Illuminate\Redis\Connections\Connection->__call('get', Array) 
5 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/Repository.php(84): Illuminate\Cache\RedisStore->get('cbwvtr3cxYIFP4H...') 
6 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/Repository.php(68): Illuminate\Cache\Repository->get('cbwvtr3cxYIFP4H...') 
7 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/CacheManager.php(305): Illuminate\Cache\Repository->has('cbwvtr3cxYIFP4H...') 
8 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/tymon/jwt-auth/src/Providers/Storage/IlluminateCacheAdapter.php(57): Illuminate\Cache\CacheManager->__call('has', Array) 
9 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/tymon/jwt-auth/src/Blacklist.php(74): Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\Storage\IlluminateCacheAdapter->has('cbwvtr3cxYIFP4H...') 
10 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/tymon/jwt-auth/src/JWTManager.php(83): Tymon\JWTAuth\Blacklist->has(Object(Tymon\JWTAuth\Payload)) 
11 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/tymon/jwt-auth/src/JWTAuth.php(190): Tymon\JWTAuth\JWTManager->decode(Object(Tymon\JWTAuth\Token)) 
12 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/tymon/jwt-auth/src/JWTAuth.php(124): Tymon\JWTAuth\JWTAuth->getPayload('eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1Q...') 
13 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/app/Http/Middleware/TokenAuthentication.php(25): Tymon\JWTAuth\JWTAuth->authenticate('eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1Q...') 
14 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): App\Http\Middleware\TokenAuthentication->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure)) 
15 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request)) 
16 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/app/Http/Middleware/WeakEtagMiddleware.php(22): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request)) 
17 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): App\Http\Middleware\WeakEtagMiddleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
```

Note I didn't make any application data changes, so my Redis code still looks like this:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis;
..

Redis::set('key', 'val');
```

Further, If I remove the default from the above config so that it looks like so:

```
'redis' => [
     'client' => 'predis',
     'cluster' => 'true',

    'clusters' => [
         'default' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST_1', '127.0.01'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => 6379,
            'database' => 0,
        ],
        'jobs' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST_2', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port'     => 6379,
            'database' => 0,
        ],
        'content' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST_3', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port'     => 6379,
            'database' => 0,
        ]
   ],

    'options' => [
        'cluster' => 'redis'
    ],
]
```

I get this error

```
[2019-06-07 16:00:02] local.ERROR: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Type error: Argument 1 passed to Predis\Connection\Parameters::__construct() must be of the type array, integer given, called in /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/Factory.php on line 164 in /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/Parameters.php:34 Stack trace: 
0 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/Factory.php(164): Predis\Connection\Parameters->__construct(6379) 
1 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/Factory.php(84): Predis\Connection\Factory->createParameters(6379) 
2 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/Factory.php(118): Predis\Connection\Factory->create(6379) 
3 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/predis/predis/src/Client.php(135): Predis\Connection\Factory->aggregate(Object(Predis\Connection\Aggregate\RedisCluster), Array) 
4 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/predis/predis/src/Client.php(56): Predis\Client->createConnection(Array) 
5 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Redis/Connectors/PredisConnector.php(41): Predis\Client->__construct(Array, Array) 
6 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Redis/RedisManager.php(102): Illuminate\Redis\Connectors\PredisConnector->connectToCluster(Array, Array, Array) 
7 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Redis/RedisManager.php(83): Illuminate\Redis\RedisManager->resolveCluster('default') 
8 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Redis/RedisManager.php(61): Illuminate\Redis\RedisManager->resolve('default') 
9 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/RedisStore.php(211): Illuminate\Redis\RedisManager->connection('default') 
10 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/RedisStore.php(54): Illuminate\Cache\RedisStore->connection() 
11 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/Repository.php(84): Illuminate\Cache\RedisStore->get('cbwvtr3cxYIFP4H...') 
12 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/Repository.php(68): Illuminate\Cache\Repository->get('cbwvtr3cxYIFP4H...') 
13 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/CacheManager.php(305): Illuminate\Cache\Repository->has('cbwvtr3cxYIFP4H...') 
14 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/tymon/jwt-auth/src/Providers/Storage/IlluminateCacheAdapter.php(57): Illuminate\Cache\CacheManager->__call('has', Array) 
15 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/tymon/jwt-auth/src/Blacklist.php(74): Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\Storage\IlluminateCacheAdapter->has('cbwvtr3cxYIFP4H...') 
16 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/tymon/jwt-auth/src/JWTManager.php(83): Tymon\JWTAuth\Blacklist->has(Object(Tymon\JWTAuth\Payload)) 
17 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/tymon/jwt-auth/src/JWTAuth.php(190): Tymon\JWTAuth\JWTManager->decode(Object(Tymon\JWTAuth\Token))
```

So from the error message it seems that Predis is simply ignoring my clustered configuration and reading straight from default, and default doesn't know how to deal with my clustered Redis data store. Ideas?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

after searching and debugging, this is what made it work:

```
'redis' => [
    'client' => 'predis',
    'cluster' => true,
    'options' => [
        'cluster' => 'redis',
        'parameters' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_DEFAULT_HOST', '127.0.01'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_DEFAULT_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 0,
            ],
        ],
    'clusters' => [
         'default' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_DEFAULT_HOST', '127.0.01'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_DEFAULT_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 0,
        ],
        'jobs' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_JOBS_HOST', '127.0.01'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_JOBS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 0,
        ],
        'content' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_CONTENT_HOST', '127.0.01'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_CONTENT_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 0,
        ],
        'options' => [
            'cluster' => 'redis'
        ],
    ]
]
```

note: one obvious mistake in my config in the above question was that i combined the host and port, which i fixed here. this is what my .env file looks like:

```
REDIS_DEFAULT_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_JOBS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_CONTENT_HOST=127.0.0.1

REDIS_DEFAULT_PORT=7000
REDIS_JOBS_PORT=7001
REDIS_CONTENT_PORT=7002
```

note: i created the cluster using the instructions here: https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial#creating-the-cluster

## Research Methodology

Due to the fact that:
1. The laravel/predis documentation on this is lacking
2. Most of the answers on stack overflow are along these lines: *after googling and searching.. this is what worked out for me* without much explanation of what's going on

I figured I can help out a bit by showing *how* I found my answer to the above.

### 1) Solving the error problem

To solve this bug

> local.ERROR: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError:
>   Type error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Predis\Connection\Parameters::__construct() must be of the type array,
>   integer given, called in
>   /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/Factory.php
>   on line 164 in
>   /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/Parameters.php:34
>   Stack trace:

I realized that my config/database.php format was simply wrong. Googling all over didn't give me any clear picture, so I decided to use [xdebug](http://www.devinbaldwin.com/2018/09/27/how-to-install-xdebug-on-a-new-mac-including-mojave/) and [dive](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/14161/14510) into the code. Note: I had the error stack trace (shown in the question above) printed in one doc, and I used that as a bird's eye view to guide me through the debug steps (ie stepping over/into/out etc while always printing the outputs in a separate doc and comparing it with my config/database.php as a sanity check/debug compass).

After digging and printig, I came across this:

```
[ *Locals ] [ Superglobals ] [ User defined constants ]

- Locals at /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/predis/predis/src/Client.php:55

 ▾ $options = (array [1])
  \
   ⬦ $options["cluster"] = (string [5]) `redis`
  /
 ▾ $parameters = (array [4])
  \
   ⬦ $parameters[0] = (string [14]) `127.0.0.1:7000`
   |
   ⬦ $parameters[1] = (null)
   |
   ⬦ $parameters[2] = (int) 6379
   |
   ⬦ $parameters[3] = (int) 0
  /
 ▾ $this = (Predis\Client [3])
  \
   ⬦ $this->connection = (null)
   |
   ⬦ $this->options = (null)
   |
   ⬦ $this->profile = (null)
  /
```

I compared this with my .env file's contents:

```
REDIS_DEFAULT_HOST=127.0.0.1:7000
REDIS_JOBS_HOST=127.0.0.1:7001
REDIS_CONTENT_HOST=127.0.0.1:7002
```

and I realized that the format was wrong, I shouldn't put the host AND port in the same env variable.. so I put it like so instead:

```
REDIS_DEFAULT_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_JOBS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_CONTENT_HOST=127.0.0.1

REDIS_DEFAULT_PORT=7000
REDIS_JOBS_PORT=7001
REDIS_CONTENT_PORT=7002
```

and that solved my first problem.

### 2) solving the other problems

after the above was fixed i got this

> CLUSTERDOWN Hash slot not served

this was was quite easy, it was just a matter of googling the error message (since the error message was clearly a native redis error message, rather than some cryptic library wrapper like predis error message).. and i found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36125071/redis-cluster-master-slave-not-able-to-add-key).

The rest was easy.

[image]

Comment: Deepest answer ❤️