# How to make Laravel broadcasting/websockets work with Redis Cluster

Tags: php, laravel, redis, redis-cluster, predis

I got a Redis Cluster server which I created by following this [tutorial](https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial#creating-the-cluster).

This is what my database/config.php setup looks like (see details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56497809/how-to-make-laravel-work-with-redis-cluster-on-aws)):

```
'redis' => [
    'client' => 'predis',
    'cluster' => true,
    'options' => [
        'cluster' => 'redis',
        'parameters' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_DEFAULT_HOST', '127.0.01'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_DEFAULT_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 0,
            ],
        ],
    'clusters' => [
         'default' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_DEFAULT_HOST', '127.0.01'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_DEFAULT_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 0,
        ],
        'jobs' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_JOBS_HOST', '127.0.01'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_JOBS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 0,
        ],
        'content' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_CONTENT_HOST', '127.0.01'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_CONTENT_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 0,
        ],
        'options' => [
            'cluster' => 'redis'
        ],
    ]
]
```

and what my config/broadcasting.php looks like:

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Broadcaster
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default broadcaster that will be used by the
    | framework when an event needs to be broadcast. You may set this to
    | any of the connections defined in the "connections" array below.
    |
    */

    'default' => env('BROADCAST_DRIVER', 'redis'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Broadcast Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define all of the broadcast connections that will be used
    | to broadcast events to other systems or over websockets. Samples of
    | each available type of connection are provided inside this array.
    |
    */

    'connections' => [

        'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
        ],

        'redis' => [
            'driver' => 'redis',
            'connection' => 'default',
        ],

        'log' => [
            'driver' => 'log',
        ],

    ],

];
```

when i reach this part in my code when i want to publish an event in redis:

```
   // Dispatch an event indicates order status has been changed.
                event(new OrderStatusChanged($order->id, OrderActionsConstants::INCOMPLETE_CART));
```

I get this error:

```
Cannot use 'PUBLISH' with redis-cluster.
```

with this stack trace

```
[2019-06-10 17:05:06] local.ERROR: 
0 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/Aggregate/RedisCluster.php(550): Predis\Connection\Aggregate\RedisCluster->getConnection(Object(Predis\Command\PubSubPublish)) 
1 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/Aggregate/RedisCluster.php(593): Predis\Connection\Aggregate\RedisCluster->retryCommandOnFailure(Object(Predis\Command\PubSubPublish), 'executeCommand') 
2 /Users/Shared$dev/php/toters-api/vendor/predis/predis/src/Client.php(331): Predis\Connection\Aggregate\RedisCluster->executeCommand(Object(Predis\Command\PubSubPublish)) 
3 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/predis/predis/src/Client.php(314): Pre$is\Client->executeCommand(Object(Predis\Command\PubSubPublish)) 
4 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Redis/Connections/Connection.php(72): Predis\Client->__call('publish', Array) 
5 /Users/Shared/de$/php/toters-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Redis/Connections/Connection.php(84): Illuminate\Redis\Connections\Connection->command('publish', Array) 
6 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/$roadcasting/Broadcasters/RedisBroadcaster.php(99): Illuminate\Redis\Connections\Connection->__call('publish', Array) 
7 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Broadcasting/BroadcastEvent.php(48): Illumin$te\Broadcasting\Broadcasters\RedisBroadcaster->broadcast(Array, 'order.status', '{"event":"order...') 
8 [internal function]: Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastEvent->handle(Object(Illuminate\Broadcasting\Broadcasters\RedisBroadcaster)) 
$ /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(29): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) 
10 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMetho$.php(87): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}() 
11 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(31): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Ob$ect(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Object(Closure)) 
12 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(539): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\Foundatio$\Application), Array, Array, NULL) 
13 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Bus/Dispatcher.php(94): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array) 
14 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/laravel/frame$ork/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(114): Illuminate\Bus\Dispatcher->Illuminate\Bus\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastEvent)) 
15 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipe$ine.php(102): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastEvent)) 
16 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Bus/Dispatcher.php(98): Illuminate\Pip$line\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure)) 
17 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/CallQueuedHandler.php(42): Illuminate\Bus\Dispatcher->dispatchNow(Object(Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastEvent), fal$e) 
18 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Jobs/Job.php(69): Illuminate\Queue\CallQueuedHandler->call(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\SyncJob), Array) 
19 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/la$avel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/SyncQueue.php(42): Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\Job->fire() 
20 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Queue.php(42): Illuminate\Queue\SyncQueue->push(Object(Illuminate$Broadcasting\BroadcastEvent), '', NULL) 
21 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Broadcasting/BroadcastManager.php(128): Illuminate\Queue\Queue->pushOn(NULL, Object(Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastEve$t)) 
22 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php(270): Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastManager->queue(Object(App\Events\OrderStatusChanged)) 
23 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vend$r/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php(193): Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher->broadcastEvent(Object(App\Events\OrderStatusChanged)) 
24 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/he$pers.php(446): Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher->dispatch('App\\Events\\Orde...') 
25 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/app/Repositories/Orders/AppOrdersRepo.php(107): event(Object(App\Events\OrderStatusChanged))
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Are your host IP addresses supposed to be `127.0.01`?

Comment: Yes.. this works on tegular redis usage but not pubsub

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You have mistake in the config file

```
config/database.php
```

when you
define one cluster, for example default i MUST contain AN ARRAY of hosts definitions

In Your particular example, the config file will be:

```
'redis' => [
'client' => 'predis',
'cluster' => true,
'options' => [
    'cluster' => 'redis',
    'parameters' => [
        'host' => env('REDIS_DEFAULT_HOST', '127.0.01'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'port' => env('REDIS_DEFAULT_PORT', 6379),
        'database' => 0,
    ],
],
'clusters' => [
    'default' => [
        [
            'host' => env('REDIS_DEFAULT_HOST', '127.0.01'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_DEFAULT_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 0,
        ]
    ],
    'jobs' => [
        [
            'host' => env('REDIS_JOBS_HOST', '127.0.01'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_JOBS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 0,
        ]
    ],
    'content' => [
        [
            'host' => env('REDIS_CONTENT_HOST', '127.0.01'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_CONTENT_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 0,
        ]
    ],
    'options' => [
        'cluster' => 'redis'
    ],
]
```

]